# ClearType conditions

Tags: windows, cleartype

Is there a way to turn on ClearType (on the OS level) for the text after some threshold? For instance, "(>= 14 pt AND Bold) OR (>18 pt) OR (Font=='SomeClearTypeOptimized.ttf')". Otherwise the text should go aliased and unsmoothed.

Regards,